# How can I check if deep links are working?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-deep-link

I would like to check if the app can be opened by a deep link. Im am wondering if there is a way to perform a check on apps defaults just like checking apps permissions with `checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed to do was query the default handler for my deep link.

```java
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity("https://my.deep.link/path", PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

`resolveInfo.activityInfo.packagename` should return either "**com.android.chrome**" or "**com.my.package**" if my package is the default